# Developing a static website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to develop a static website . So far as what I have understood and setup is a folder which contains the css,images folder and a index.html. Since I am trying to host it on amazon s3 I have also made the index.html as the landing page. So I have a projects tab which clicked on would go to a new page where I could display my projects . So my question is should I be having a projects.html under which I have my projects introduction . When clicked on read more for each project should I be redirecting it to a  new html.

```
root/
     css/
     images/
     index.html
     resume.html
     projects/
              projects_landing_page.html
              project1.html
              project2.html
              project3.html
```

Is this the right folder structure to maintain a static website.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*Should I be having a projects.html under which I have my projects introduction . When clicked on read more for each project should I be redirecting it to a new html.*"

In my opinion, each project should occupy its own page, as I'm assuming each page could get quite complex. On top of this, you don't want data about a particular project on the same page as data about an unrelated project. If they have synonymous data (such as a navbar), it would be best to inject that with a server-side language such as PHP.

> "*Is this the right folder structure to maintain a static website.*"

"*Right folder structure*" is highly subjective. Technically, there is no **wrong** structure, as you can access any file from any other file, regardless of how complex the action to do so becomes.

Having said that, you generally want to keep all 'associated' files together in a folder that describes what the files are. You have an excellent structure yourself -- pages are very clearly separated. However, I would typically move the `projects_landing_page.html` file to the root level myself:

```
root/
     css/
         style.css
     images/
         image1.jpg
         image2.png
     index.html
     resume.html
     projects_landing_page.html
     projects/
              project1.html
              project2.html
              project3.html
```

In your `projects_landing_page.html`, I would then refer to each link with the following syntax:

```
<a href="projects/project1.html">
<a href="projects/project2.html">
```

This really comes down to personal preference though, as either approach is perfectly valid.

Hope this helps! :)